# How can I place DistributionChart at desired x values?

Tags: plotting, charts

Consider a simple `DistributionChart` such as the following:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], 100], {3}];
DistributionChart[data]
```

[image]

I want to center those three violins at desired x values on an actual x-axis (not just label them using `ChartLabels`), for example at `x = {1.1, 2.5, 4.0}`. The resulting horizontal spacing between the violins will depend on the `x` list and I should be able to `Show` the resulting plot overlaid with a regular `Plot`, `ListPlot`, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], 100], {3}];
```

A bit hacky, but these polygons are generated and translated to positions {1.,0.},{2.,0.} and {3.,0.} respectively. This can be changed by finding the positions where these translations are happening.

Starting with chart `p2`, locate where the `GeometricTransformation` is happening and append the `{2,2}` which is the `x` translation component:

```
p2 = DistributionChart[data]

pos = Join[#, {2, 2}] & /@ Position[p2, GeometricTransformation[_, _]]

xpos = {1.1, 2.5, 4.0};
xtx = {#, 0} & /@ xpos;
```

Change the translation:

```
Table[Part[p2, Sequence @@ pos[[i]]] = xtx[[i]], {i, Length@pos}]
```

Now, superimpose on `p1` which is a sin curve for reference.

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: This works nicely. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the accept.